# What is the probability that landing point of projectile is a specific value ?

Tags: probability

A catapult throws a stone onder the angle Q with horizon (simple projectile motion) a random variable Q (angle) takes values in interval (alpha,2*alpha), the density of Q is zero in alpha and increase linear up to 2*alpha.R is the horizontal distance from the catapult and is also a random variable which is uniformly distributed in interval (0,rho*Q). rho and alpha are constants, and alpha takes value in (0,Pi/8). What is the probability that the stone lands in interval (0,rho*alpha)? 
I tried to write the density for R so P(Ralpha) = int(1/(rhoQ),0..rho*alpha) , but the integral is for sure not convergent ! so  i got stuck here !

Comment: Proper formatting is expected; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Mrz Farjamirad Please write out the integral here which does not converge.